# Enum with underlying type. Returning the string representation unintentionally

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following enum:

```
 public enum BikeType : byte
  {
    Road = 0,
    Mountain = 1
  };
```

When I try to pass it to a I retrieve the 'string' representation of the byte, not the numeric value:

`string str = string.Format("Road bike has a byte value of {0}", BikeType.Road);`

```
"Road bike has a byte value of Road"
```

I want the byte value (0).  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do casting to int

```
string str = 
          string.Format("Road bike has a byte value of {0}", (int)BikeType.Road);
```

If you don't cast it it will call `ToString` on `BikeType.Road` which will return `Road`

Comment: In fact, it will call `.ToString()` on everything which is not `string` itself.

Comment: @AgentFire yes it will, but I was refering this example :)

Answer (score 4):

You should cast to `byte`

```
string str = string.Format("Road bike has a byte value of {0}", (byte)BikeType.Road);
```

Comment: Actually, this is the most correct answer. `byte` is the underlying type. Casting to `int` would be coercing the value into a larger datatype because the enum was defined using `byte` as its underlying type.